# If I'm floating in a vacuum, can I move an object of any mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

If I'm floating in a vacuum, is it possible for me to move an object that on Earth weights 1000 tons? Do I understand correctly that any mass will be moved and accelerated proportional to my weight and the acceleration with which I push it and moving forever?

Does this work in real life, or are there forces that impede this? Let's say a meteor from space hits the earth at standard meteor velocity, it weights on Earth about a ton. Was the Earth's speed affected by this permanently in theory, even if impossible to measure?

Comment: The acceleration is related to mass. As you push, the inertia of the mass kicks in, and you simply end up pushing yourself away, barely budging the mass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. By $F = ma$, as long as you exert a net force, you'll cause an acceleration. In the "vacuum" you're thinking of (i.e. no gravitational force) there is no friction or resistance force so any force you exert will be the net force and there'll be an acceleration.

> Let's say a meteor from space hits the earth at standard meteor velocity, it weights on Earth about a ton. Was the Earth's speed affected by this permanently in theory, even if impossible to measure?

Yes it was permanently affected by this in theory.